# CEdit CR or LF pushing to next line?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc

When outputting text to CEdit, how can I alter the multiline to set it up so that only when a "\n" will it go to the next line?

ie:(setup programmatically)

```
CEdit *myEdit1 = new CEdit;
myEdit1->Create( ES_MULTILINE | ES_READONLY | WS_VISIBLE | WS_BORDER, CRect(800,100,900,200), this, 2);
```

if I feed this "\n" I want a the it to go to the next line (and only then)

```
CString s;
s = "hello \n there";
myEdit1->SetWindowText(s);
```

Comment: This is Windows, use `"\r\n"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need to subclass CEdit to handle the keystrokes in that case. Otherwise the default behavior is to use <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Enter</kbd> to jump to next line.

Just search for CEDit subclassing and you will get lots of examples.